# Find tuples with certain keywords

Tags: python

I have a tuple with 3grams that looks like this:

```
from nltk import ngrams
test_data = ["this is all test data", "this not"]

three_gram_list = []
for data in test_data:
 three_grams = ngrams(data.split(" "), 3)
 for gram in three_grams:
  three_gram_list.append(gram)
```

What I would like to do is to create a function that checks for each 3-gram whether words are used in the same tuple. Therefore I did the following:

```
def create_specific_trigram(three_grams, parameters1, parameters2):

 condition1 = False
 condition2 = False

 for three in three_grams:
     for num in range(1, 3):
         if three[num] in parameters1:
            condition1 = True

      for num in range(1, 3):
          if three[num] in parameters2:
              condition2 = True

      if condition1 and condition2:
          print(three)
```

However I run it now with some parameters:

```
parameters1 = ("test", "testing")
parameters2 = ("data", "datas")

for sentence in test_data:
  create_specific_trigram(three_grams, paramaters1, parameters2)
```

I get the following output.

```
('all', 'test', 'data')
('all', 'test', 'data')
```

However I am only looking for one output per sentence. So in this case:

```
('all', 'test', 'data')
```

Any thoughts on what changes I should apply?

Comment: Is there some reason why you're only testing `three[1]` and `three[2]` but not `three[0]?`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? Are you trying to get all combinations of three words that contain an element from `parameters1` and an element from `parameters2`? As it is, the code you have provided here will not run due to indentation errors and typos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When launching the function `create_specific_trigram`, you launch it for the same value of `three_grams`, independent from `sentence`.

Try this:

```
test_data = ["this is all test data", "this not"]
parameters1 = ("test", "testing")
parameters2 = ("data", "datas")

#============================================
#implementation of create_specific_trigram
# ...
#============================================

for sentence in test_data:
  three_grams = ngrams(sentence.split(" "), 3)
  create_specific_trigram(three_grams, paramaters1, parameters2)
```